# Auto-wiring: 2 application libraries (services) wanting to talk to each other

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony4, autowired

I've come across a problem with the auto-wiring approach to dependency injection for libraries registered as application services, when 2 libraries want bi-directional access to (some of) each others' public functions.

It appears that if you try to inject service A into service B and vice versa you will end up with a circular reference error:

`Circular reference detected for service "App\Library\ServiceALibrary", path: "App\Library\ServiceALibrary-> App\Library\ServiceBLibrary -> App\Library\ServiceALibrary".`

--

A crude example... Let's imagine these 2 service libraries:

- LanguageLib: Responsible for handling translations that are manageable within an administration interface. (Database stored rather than a bunch files in the application's source.)
- SlugLib: Responsible for generating string based slugs and tags using predefined formats. *Yes I know about Cocur/Slugify, that's irrelevant right now.*

A new phrase comes along that the language tables don't know about, so the language library in its `translate()` function will create a stub phrase so it's ready for translation later on.

The language library will now ask the slug library to provide a tag in a specific format. But oh no! The slug library doesn't like something about the argument the language library, so it throws back a translated error message. That of course means asking the language library's translate function for that message.

You need not worry about the exact model logic here. What's important is that 2 service libraries want to be able to use each other's public functions within their own logic, whilst avoiding duplication by having a copy of the function in both libraries.

--

On to the problem.

In previous (very previous) versions of Symfony it was acceptable to inject the service container into libraries, then each library could grab the instance of another service via something like `$this->container->get("languageLib")`. I could continue to do this even on Symfony 4, but the current "best practises" go on to tell me how very wrong I am for doing this. *I am happy being open to the latest best practises, if they are feasible.*

How does one go about having 2 service libraries being able to use each others' public functionality conforming to Symfony 4 standards? (Not injecting the service container.)

I did try creating interfaces for these libraries, `SlugLibraryInterface` and `LanguageLibraryInterface` for example, then inject the interface into the library constructors instead of the library class itself:

- Type hint `LanguageLibraryInterface` in `SlugLibrary::__construct()`
- Type hint `SlugLibraryInterface` in `LanguageLibrary::__construct()`

This did not solve the circular reference issue, command `php bin/console debug:autowiring` still claimed the library classes (not interface classes) had a circular reference.